# Android RecyclerView Scrolls When Selecting Text Within WebView Child

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app which utilizes a list of items, varying in layouts.  One item is a WebView which renders HTML supplied by my client via their web service.

When I long press on text within the WebView list item, it selects the text but automatically scrolls the RecyclerView.

How can I prevent the RecyclerView from scrolling when text is selected?  I have attempted to disable the RecyclerView and reenable it after some time, but it appears the scroll has already been dispatched to the RecyclerView.

Thanks,
Adam

Edit: When I declare windowActionModeOverlay true for my style the scrolling happens.  When I declare windowActionModeOverlay false the scrolling isn't as bad.

Comment: From personal experience, putting a scroll view inside a scroll view will only cause you pain and heartbreak.

Comment: I believe that.  I have experienced some heartbreak with this implementation.  I need to use a WebView because the content returned by the server is in HTML, and needs to link out with specific app links.  If there was an easier way to do that with a TextView (or fancier TextView) I am game.

Comment: off the top of my head, a hacky way might be to detect when the context menu is shown and grab the scrollY of the recycler view before/after then set the scrollY such that the scroll appears to not actually happen.  Only problem might be a flicker effect if a draw happens during the setScrollY